# Logcat is empty in android studio even it is showing in android device monitor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

My android studio is showing empty logcat, even it is not empty in android device monitor. I have attached some screenshots of my project:
[image: Screenshot of empty logcat]

[image: Android Device Monitor Screenshot]
[image: After running project, it shows unwanted values]

After running project, logcat showing unwanted values. This is happening in this project only, in other projects logcat is fine. Please help me in this issue.

Comment: Try clean,and  rebuilding project and reconnecting the device, if still issue remains then go to File --> Invalidate cache/Restart.

Comment: @Yesha Shah, I have tried to clean build myproject, reconnect my device and also invalidate cache/Restart, nothing is working

Comment: have you deleted the apk once and then tried for clean, rebuild your project ? @harshita

Comment: @harshita Try like click on `File` option -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart...` then try to debug and check logcat.

Comment: @Nitin Patel Hello Sir, i have already tried it two times nothing has happened.

Answer (score 1):

As per your first screenshot attached I can see that you have selected the Android debug device as SAMSUNG SM - J700F but you have not selected any Debuggable Process (Any Applciation). So if your project is running in Android studio and the same app is running on selected Android Debug device than your Project will be visible in dropdown between the SAMSUNG SM - J700F and Verbose dropdown. Make sure you click on that dropdown in which the current value is shown as **No Debuggable Process** is visible and select your appropriate project.

Comment: Try changing the value from Verbose to Debug.

Answer (score 0):

Check in Tools--> Android--> Enable ADB Integration is enabled or not, if not please enable it.[image]

And as shown in the above image select "Show only selected aplication" in your logcat.